# Detect buffered size of file in php

Tags: php, stream, streaming

How can I detect if user has buffered half of a file when Im serving the file with php?

I want to add stats for the file when user reachs to half of a file when downloading or streaming it.

For example there is file which is 3 MB and I need to add stats to my database when user has reached to half of it by streaming

```
    while(!feof($fm) && $cur <= $end && (connection_status() == 0))
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['plays'][$pid])) {
            $_SESSION['plays'][$pid] = [
                'status' => 0,
                'buffered' => 0,
                'passed' => $size/2
            ];
        }
        $bytes = min(1024 * 16, ($end - $cur) + 1);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        echo fread($fm, $bytes);
        $cur += 1024 * 16;
        $_SESSION['plays'][$pid]['buffered'] += $bytes;
        if(!$_SESSION['plays'][$pid]['status'] && $_SESSION['plays'][$pid]['buffered']>$_SESSION['plays'][$pid]['passed']) {
            $_SESSION['plays'][$pid]['status'] = 1;
            $dataToSend = [
                'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                'user_id' => $userId,
                'post_id' => $pid,
                'type' => 'play',
                'client_id' => isset($decoded->aud) ? $decoded->aud : null,
            ];
        }
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
```